# Tecno N3 keeps rebooting

Tags: boot-loop, tecno-n3

In my case, my tecno n3 keeps rebooting even with the sd card removed. What can I do? Pls help.

Didn't install any new apps recently.
Only followed Barca_Ac Milan commentary online.

Also, how do I hard reset the phone?

Comment: Do you mean factory reset instead of hard reset? As in clear user data?

Comment: Did you check the initial help in the tag-wiki for "boot-loop"? (Simply hover your mouse over the tag, and in the popup click the "info" link. Quite often that place already contains initial help. For your convenience: [click here](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Press Vol up + Power button for about 4 seconds, keep until reset menu appears.